# Checkboxes only sending one value to the server

Tags: html, forms, dojo

I have a widget with the following code in its template:

```
<div class="inputField is-company">
  <label for="${id}_isCompany">Company?</label>
  <input id="${id}_isCompany" name="isCompany" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" data-dojo-attach-point="isCompanyWidget" data-dojo-props: "" value="on" />
</div>
```

The problem is that when the form is submitted, formWidget.get('value') returns `isCompany` as an array, which can be empty or it can contain `on`.

On the server, all I need (and want) is a simple value, "true" or "false", for that field.

What's the simplest path to get this behaviour from the Dojo form?

At the moment, I am doing this:

BEFORE sending the form:

```
values.isCompany = values.isCompany.indexOf( 'on' ) !== -1;
```

This way, I only send to the server a proper "flag" value.

When form has values assigned:

```
if( res.isCompany ) this.isCompanyWidget.set('value', true );
```

Otherwise, the checkbox widget won't get a tick if it's supposed to be ticked.

However, it "feels like too much work" so to speak...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is normal behavior that the `dijit/form/CheckBox` returns an array. The reasoning behind this is that like in plain HTML you can define the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red" checked />
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="yellow" />
```

In this case, `colors` will contain an array of all selected colors (which are the values). So it makes sense that Dojo is following the same strategy. This means you will have to manually translate the array to a single value (because your use case is different from what the checkbox is originally designed for).

But since you're actually interested in if the checkbox is checked or not, I think it makes more sense to do something like this:

```js
form.on("submit", function() {
    var values = form.getValues();
    lang.mixin(values, {
        isCompany: registry.byId("isCompany").get("checked") 
    });
    console.log(values);
});
```

This way your form won't break when the value changes. The `lang.mixin()` part is just a fancy way to say that you want to combine the second object into the first, overriding properties if they already exist (in this case the `isCompany` property).

I also made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g00glen00b/vRjwU/).

Comment: Suspected as much. Thank you for the long explanation!